# Overfitting in K-means

Tags: k-means, overfitting

How do you test your results for overfitting in a k-means run? Some people have said use a training set. I have about 1500 records and about 20 fields.

Comment: You can't overfit K-Means. It can, however, be non-robust. It's unsupervised learning, not supervised. Keywords for theory: silhouette analysis, elbow method, gap statistics, mutual information

Comment: @CarlRynegardh although [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/294808/195246) shares the same opinion, [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/20292/67328) seems quite reasonable too. We can settle for a subjective overfitting I think!

Answer (score 0):

You can compare k-means clustering peformance between a training and validation dataset. If the performance between the two datasets is too different for the given problem, reduce the number of clusters (i.e., the k in k-means clustering).

Comment: Is it advisable to split a dataset into train and test for a clustering algorithm? Don't we just use the full dataset?

Comment: Splitting a dataset into train and test is one of the best ways to evaluate overffiting. If you don't care about overfitting, then do not do a train/test split.

Comment: Yes I know that but should we split the data when building a **clustering** model?